# "Type Error : is not a function" in a Jest test

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

A component tested by Jest and Enzyme has some function. Then this function uses an imported library.

It makes some error.

#### Test code

```js
it('Emoji should be rendered without error', () => {
    const messageItem = shallow(
      <MessageItem {...props}/>
    )
   ...
})
```

#### MessageItem

```js
import * as getUrls from 'get-urls';

export class MessageItem extends Component <Props> {
  state = {
    isOpenThread: false,
    isAddEmoji: false,
    containedUrl: ''
  }

  getContainUrl = () => {
    //getUrls makes an error!
    const urls = getUrls(this.props.content).values();
    const firstUrl: string = urls.next().value;
    return firstUrl
  }
  ...
  render(){
    return (... <UrlInfoArea {...props} url={this.getContainUrl()} />))
  }
}
```

#### Error message

```
 TypeError: getUrls is not a function

      37 |
      38 |   getContainUrl = () => {
    > 39 |     const urls = getUrls(this.props.content).values();
         |                  ^
      40 |     const firstUrl: string = urls.next().value;
      41 |     return firstUrl
      42 |   }
```

It works normally at runtime.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Can you share your `tsconfig.json`?

Try adding `"esModuleInterop": true` to your `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: i tried it. but it is same status.                                                                                {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"]
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/node_modules/*"]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get-urls` exports a single function and the type definitions for `get-urls` [uses the `export =` syntax](https://github.com/sindresorhus/get-urls/blob/31f483b7e4c6776388d29dc37a4867f94de06d76/index.d.ts#L40).

Based on the [TypeScript documentation on `export =`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require) the proper way to import `get-urls` would be to use the `import = require()` syntax like this:

```
import getUrls = require('get-urls');
```

Comment: it is the make error in typesscript like that' ECMAScript modules. Consider using 'import * as ns from "mod"', 'import {a} from "mod"', 'import d from "mod"', or another module format instead.ts(1202)'